# Windows System Sounds not playing (Windows 8.1 x64)

Tags: windows, audio, windows-8.1, windows-services, system-sounds

In the Volume Mixer, when I drag the "Speakers" master volume level slider, I hear the expected Ding. But When I drag the System Sounds slider, nothing.

Sound from applications is working normally. I have already checked the following:

- "System Sounds" volume level in Volume Mixer is not 0
- "Playback Devices" Playback tab: default playback device is set correctly, and I can hear the "Test" tones.
- "Sounds" tab: Sound Scheme is set, and I changed it to the "Default" Scheme. Using the "Test" button on a sound in this tab plays the sound correctly.
- Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services are running (automatic)
- Event log: searched System log for sound-related events (nothing found)
- Performed `sfc /scannow`
- Performed full malware scan with Windows Defender

Comment: To Mr. Anonymous Downvoter: Why would you downvote this question, without even leaving a comment? To me it clearly shows research effort (look at all the things I tried). And I think it is entirely clear, and obviously useful to anyone in the same situation. And there are plenty of us out there.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and it had me stumped for a few days.

The solution was that I had inadvertently turned the system sounds volume control in the sound mixer to zero! You can set the various sound sources separately in the mixer.

[image: mixer screenshot with system sounds turned to zero]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the cause was, but I was able to fix it by doing a system restore.